# Not able to start weblogic 12.2.1.4 in genuitec myeclipse

Tags: weblogic12c, myeclipse

```
 <Info> <RCM> <BEA-2165021> <"ResourceManagement" is not enabled in this JVM. Enable "ResourceManagement" to use the WebLogic Server "Resource Consumption Management" feature. To enable "ResourceManagement", you must specify the following JVM options in the WebLogic Server instance in which the JVM runs: -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+ResourceManagement.>
```

Comment: I'm have same error too